# Sitemap nodes appear on the same line in menu

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have an asp.net sitemap. I have child sitemap nodes "Mediterranean Fruits", "Apple" and "Orange" under the parent sitemap node "Fruits"

This sitemap is bound to an asp.net menu control.

The problem is "Apple" and "Orange" appear on the same line in the menu displayed in the browser.

It is displayed as

1) Fruits     2)Mediterranean Fruits    3)Apple Orange

I want them to appear one below the other like

1)Fruits    2)Mediterranean Fruits    3)Apple    4)Orange

Could you please let me know how this can be done.

Thanks

Comment: "On the same line" meaning in the browser or in the code? Please show us some mark-up, preferably both server side and client side.

Comment: Show the relevant parts of the sitemap you created please.